# How can I run a shell command without being added in history?

Tags: shell, command, command-history

How can I run a shell command without being added in history? I don't want to purge the command history, I just don't want my next shell command doesn't show up in the history. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, to prevent a command from being added to history, put a space before the command.  This is assumes that you have, as is common, the `ignorespace` option set in `HISTCONTROL`.  If you don't, run the following command (or add it to `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent):

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Many people also want to ignore duplicate commands, in which case use:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
```

If you want to ignore certain commands always, then use `HISTIGNORE`.  For example, the following setting will always ignore `sudo poweroff`, `sudo shutdown` followed by any options, and `sudo reboot`:

```
export HISTIGNORE="sudo poweroff:sudo shutdown*:sudo reboot"
```